# Does CVEs reported in a Java Update applies also to previous updates?

Tags: java, cve

If my application uses *JRE 1.8.0_6*, that have currently 3 CVEs reported, all later updates' CVEs sums up to 216, and 34 CVEs reported in *JRE 1.8.0* in general, what is the number of vulnerabilities my application is potentially exposed to 3, 3+34, 3+216, or 3+216+34, and why?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to determine the number of relevant CVE just based on the numbers you show. For example a CVE shown for Java 8u131 might have been just recently introduced in Java 8u130 or it might already have been lurking in the code since Java6. Thus in order to to get which CVE are relevant for your Java version you need to dig through the details of all the later CVE and look for which versions they apply. If they apply already for Java 7 then the chance is high that the bug is also in the older Java 8 version you use.

Apart from that: who cares about the exact number (and only about the number). Relevant for assessing the risk you have when using an old Java version is not the total number of CVE but which of these actually affect your application, how bad they are and how they can be mitigated.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle used to figure out what versions of Java vulnerabilities were introduced in, however with Java 8 Oracle only says that a vulnerability is in the latest version of a branch (Java 6, 7 or 8).  The safe thing to do (and what I instruct our teams) is to assume that any vulnerability is in all previous versions of Java.  It won't always be true, but it's the safest thing to assume.

Steffan is correct that you want to understand if a vulnerability is exploitable or not (aka a vulnerability assessment).  Unfortunately, when Oracle made the change noted above they also made their vulnerability descriptions much more vague.  For example, the description for [CVE-2017-10116](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-10116) (which was fixed in the July Quarterly Critical Patch Update) states "Difficult to exploit vulnerability allows unauthenticated attacker with network access via multiple protocols to compromise Java SE, Java SE Embedded, JRockit. Successful attacks require human interaction from a person other than the attacker and while the vulnerability is in Java SE ..."  With that description you'd have to assume that any protocol is vulnerable.  You can often find better descriptions on Red Hat's site.  Go to the [CVE link there](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2017-10116) and then click on the Bugzilla link and you get a much more useful description of the issue: "It was discovered that the LDAPCertStore class in the Security component of OpenJDK followed LDAP referrals to arbitrary URLs.  A specially-crafted LDAP referral URL could cause LDAPCertStore to communicate with non-LDAP servers."  Red Hat won't always have a Bugzilla and if they do occasionally it will be restricted, but it usually gives you a lot more information.

Comment: Why would you assume that a vulnerability exists in all previous versions/update? Since the new version has new code in it, isn't it more reasonable that CVEs are referring only the specific version/update it was found in?

In other words, and without getting into details on the CVEs, let's assume that statistically if a software has more CVEs it's potentially less secured,  then if you would have to choose between U6 which (currently) have 3 CVEs or U131 which have 28 CVEs, you would go with 131, is that correct?

Comment: 1. I make that assumption because it's the safest one from a security perspective.

Comment: 1. I make that assumption because it's the safest one from a security perspective.  In other words, assume it's there and prove that it's not.

2. While not unheard of, it's pretty rare that a vulnerability is introduced in one version, found and then fixed in the next version.  Take a look curl's security page (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/security.html), where the project does tell you every vulnerability (68 in total), the version it was introduced in and the version it was fixed in.  You'll notice that only ONE TIME was a vulnerability introduced, found and then fixed in the next version.